# Present View Controller without calling presentViewController (or dismissViewController)

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uistoryboard, segue

I am in the process of building a reasonably complex iPad app that will run on iOS7+.  The app has a login screen that must be accessed once every user session, this is the starting view controller in my storyboard.  The user can log out from any other screen in the app (there are about 60 other screens) by touching a button that is always available in every other ViewController.  When the user logs out, a custom transition animation should be used.

It seems I can achieve this in one of two ways, either with a segue from every screen in the app to the login page, which makes the storyboard impossible to read, or presentViewController.

I've implemented this with presentViewController, by looking up the view controller by id from the storyboard (which creates a new instance, which is a desired behavior) and then presenting it from the current view controller.

Not surprisingly, this does not dismiss the original login view controller and essentially creates a stack of view controllers, eventually I run out of memory as each time a user logs out, a new login view controller is created and retained.

Is there a way to clear this "stack" of view controllers?

Is there a different way to present a view controller, with an animation, that does not involve presentViewController or segues?  I've considered view controller containment, but that doesn't seem quite right when used with storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered replacing the root view controller?  If the app delegate observes a logout notification and replaces the root view controller with the initial content of the storyboard that should get the app back to the initial screen.

I've seen that presented as a solution for login/logout issues elsewhere on the web, but I'm not sure if there's a transition you can animate there.

Comment: I was actually able to do it in the completion block for presentViewController.  I had tried this before, but it turns out I had a retain cycle somewhere else that was preventing my previous view controller from being released.  I incorrectly assumed the retain was coming from the pointer to presentingViewController in the view controller I was presenting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong.  **Correct me else wise**.

Login mechanisms are supposed to be singleton instances. Hence you should define your view controllers, models, views all as singleton instances. Please look at my following code for example.

```
static id objectInstance;

+ (id) sharedInstanceID {
    if (!objectInstance) {
        objectInstance = [[YourClass alloc] init];
    }
    return objectInstance;
}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I'm using storyboards, and as such every view controller is instantiated (and likewise deallocated) by the storyboard.  My app by its nature can be a bit memory intensive, so I don't want a lot of extra view controllers laying around in memory.  Essentially, on log out, I want it to forget everything it used to know so I can start over.

Comment: I think your question is at a higher level against programming (abstract with architecture of your app). Can you share your app's architecture? Do you use navigation controllers, if so, you can just call `self.navigationController popToRootViewController` or so. Else, I'm sure you are using some stack or queue to maintain all the controllers, and again you can dealloc them. I need more input to help you.

Comment: No navigation controllers.  The app is used for a business, as a kiosk, each user logs in, completes a task, and then logs out.  Tasks can be long and involved, encompassing multiple screens, and can be exited at any point by logging out.  When the user logs out, all state is cleared.  Essentially, I want to perform a custom-animated transition back to the login screen and reset everything else.  If it helps, I briefly considered just replacing the window's rootViewController with the login controller, but I could not make the animated transition work for it.